# ¿Cómo importar un JSON con listas a expandir en R?

Tags: json, r, dataframe

A ver si me explico bien, tengo un JSON de este tipo:

```
   [{"id_receta":"receta1",
    "materiales": ["material1", "material2", 
    "material3","material4","material5","material6"],
    "cantidades": [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]},
   {"id_receta":"receta2",
    "materiales": ["material1", "material2", 
    "material3","material4","material5","material6"],
    "cantidades": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]}]
```

Lo que quiero es que pasarlo a un dataframe de R, de manera que por cada material se cree una linea con el id_receta, el material y la cantidad.

He probado con (de la librería jsonlite):

```
recetas <- as.data.frame(fromJSON("data/test.json"))
```

Y, si es una sola receta, sin problema, lo hace a la primera, cuando meto más recetas simplemente guarda los materiales y las cantidades como una lista en el dataframe.

¿Algún consejo sobre esto?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes posibilidad de cargar `tidyr/tidyverse` tienes la función `unnest()` para "expandir" cada lista en filas:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

fromJSON("data/test.json") %>% 
    unnest(-id_receta)

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   id_receta materiales cantidades
   <chr>     <chr>           <int>
 1 receta1   material1           4
 2 receta1   material2           8
 3 receta1   material3          15
 4 receta1   material4          16
 5 receta1   material5          23
 6 receta1   material6          42
 7 receta2   material1           1
 8 receta2   material2           1
 9 receta2   material3           2
10 receta2   material4           3
11 receta2   material5           5
12 receta2   material6           8
```

Comment: Si, efectivamente eso, ya le estaba dando yo muchas vueltas a como hacerlo, y ahí está. Muchas gracias!